# Django Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'testserver'. You may need to add u'testserver' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django

I started learning Django, I'm in the middle of implementing "Test a view" functionality.
When I use **test Client** in the shell, the exception has occurred as follows.

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'testserver'. You may need to add u'testserver' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

I run the command in the shell as follows.

```
>>> from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
>>> setup_test_environment()
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> client = Client()
>>> response = client.get('/')
>>> response.status_code
400
```

In the tutorial, 404 should be appeared, but I get 400.
When I continue running the command as follows, same exception has occurred.

```
>>> response = client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
>>> response.status_code
400
```

but the result must be 200.I guess I should declare **ALLOWED_HOSTS** in the **settings.py**, but how can I?
I run the server on localhost using *$python manage.py runserver*.

I wanna know the reason and solution.

Here is settings.py as follows.

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = '8v57o6wyupthi^#41_yfg4vsx6s($1$x0xmu*95_u93wwy0_&u'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [127.0.0.1,'localhost']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
]
....    (MIDDLEWARE)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'tutorial.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tutorial.wsgi.application'
....    (DATABASES, AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS)
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: is your debug false?

Comment: Thanks for contacting me. Yeah, debug is false

Comment: then inside allowed host put 127.0.0.1,localhost and check

Comment: Should I declare ALLOWED_HOSTS in the settings.py file?

Comment: there is an allowed host variable just after debug, inside it put it , if you dont have it, declare it with all caps and put the 2 inside like ALLOWED_HOSTS=[127.0.0.1,'localhost']

Comment: I write ALLOWED_HOSTS=[127.0.0.1,'localhost'] in settings.py file, but syntax error occur.

Comment: what error? tell me

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS = [127.0.*0*.1,'localhost'] -> syntax error. SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: why the * are there? remove them, only 127.0.0.1

Comment: syntax error point out there.

Comment: post your settings file in the question

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Edit the following line in your `settings.py` file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

Restart your server afterwards

Comment: in file settings.py

Answer (score 12):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['XXX.iptime.org', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'testserver']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: For the more info here is the link - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Answer (score 10):

Adding 'testserver', 'localhost', or '127.0.0.1' did not work for me (Django >3.1).

What did was initiating the client with a different server name:

```
c = Client(SERVER_NAME='localhost')
```

Note that I got an error mentioning I needed to add 'testserver', but that I initiate the client with 'localhost'.

Answer (score 5):

You should edit it like that:

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
      '127.0.0.1',
      'localhost',
      'testserver',
]

Comment: you have '172.0.0.1', but it should be '127.0.0.1'

Answer (score 3):

**This worked for me**
you can try this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS += ['testserver']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try for testing purpose

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Answer (score 0):

settings.py is in read-only mode

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

this is how to save it

Comment: if file read-only mode, then using the terminal in ubuntu move to the path and try sudo su and gedit settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the correct answers, there is an important check which you need to keep in mind. Setting ALLOWED_HOSTS with a single valued tuple will still give you same error, for example if you set it this way:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=('testserver')
```

It does not work, because you may wanted to make this a tuple but ACTUALLY it is a string in Python, yes thats strange but true! you can read more about tuples here: [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

If you want to make it a tuple, you need to add a comma like this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=('testserver',)
```

This works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` file, you can simply update `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`. But yes, you can also use solutions provided by others too but to keep it short and simple you can go with this

Comment: Not a good idea to open it up completely like this. Also, there's an answer from over three years ago that already suggests this, with a warning. Please don't repeat answers.