# Do we have to host our Django site for our Flutter App backend?

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework, deployment, hosting

Suppose I am creating a todo list app in Flutter. I have used Django to connect flutter's backend with the local host database. Now my API's(Django Rest Framework) are working fine if the is on local machine. But what if I deploy my Flutter app to Play Store? Then I need to host my Django site as well or it can be upon the local machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Development**

If you are in development the local machine is enough. For connecting the Flutter app to the Django development server follow the steps below.

1. connect your local server and mobile device to the same network (for example, a common wi-fi)
2. Get the IP address of the local machine. In Linux, the command is `ifconfig`,
   and in Windows, it is `ipconfig`. It will be something like `192.168.1.8`
3. Run the Django server with the following command in the terminal, providing your IP address you got in step 2:

   `python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.8:8000`
4. To test, try access the IP address (with port) via. a browser on the phone. If it loads, the connection is correctly set up
5. Now you can use this address in your request in the HTTP request in Flutter

**Production**

If you are deploying the app in production, you can host a server (AWS/EC2, for example). You will get the IP address somewhere in the console. Deploy the code to the server and run the code there. Replace the local IP address in app with the IP address of the server. You can also use packages like Environ for this.

Comment: **And Add ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost'] in setting.py**   \n                                  
If this error occurs :You may need to add u'testserver' to ALLOWED_HOSTS 
 [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184268/django-invalid-http-host-header-testserver-you-may-need-to-add-utestserver)